# Python selenium webriver misses elements without giving any error

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I've been using selenium ChromeDriver to parse some information. I've found elements I need by XPath, saved them into the list and then wrote a for loop to click on each of the element. It worked perfectly when I had a small amount of elements (>30), but now I'm facing a problem, that the length of my list is shorter than the actual amount of elements on the webpage (like 30 from 112, or 45 from 210). But all of these elements have the same XPath I've located initially.

```
# login function
def login(email,password):
    driver.get('https://crm.tender-win.ru/account/logon')
    driver.find_element_by_id('email').send_keys(email)
    driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys(password)
    driver.find_element_by_id('btnLogin').click()

df = []
login('somelogin','somepassword')
driver.get('https://crm.tender-win.ru/tenders/new')
WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'MyTenderMenuTabsInfo')))
tenders = [driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card ']") 
           or driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card new']")][0]

for tender in tenders:
    tender.click()
    WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tenderCurrencyCode')))
    data = driver \
        .find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="infoScroll"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table') \
        .get_attribute('outerHTML')
    
    df1 = pd.read_html(data)
    df.append(df1)
    print(df)
```

P.S.

I solved my issuse by turning for loop into function and using it until my list with elemenets is empty.

```
def clicker(tenders=None):
    for tender in tenders:
        tender.click()
        WebDriverWait(driver, 10).until(EC.presence_of_element_located((By.ID, 'tenderCurrencyCode')))
        data = driver \
            .find_element_by_xpath('//*[@id="infoScroll"]/div/div[3]/div[2]/table') \
            .get_attribute('outerHTML')
        df1 = pd.read_html(data)
        df.append(df1)
        print(df)
def scrape():
    tenders = [driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card ']")
          or driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card new']")][0]
    while len(tenders) > 0:
        clicker(tenders)
        tenders = [driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card ']") 
                   or driver.find_elements_by_xpath("//div[@class='panel card new']")][0]
```

Comment: If no elements are found, the `tenders` list will be empty your code will just exit.

Comment: But my list is not empty. I'm able to locate all the elements, when their amount is small, but when it's gets bigger, my list locates smth like quarter of them. All the elements have the XPath `//div[@class='panel card ']` or `//div[@class='panel card new]`. So thereotically I should be able to locate all ot them

Comment: You should not write the solution in the question. You should create an answer to your own question with the solution instead and accept it.